# Converting string from Python3 to dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I convert this string bellow from `Python3` to a `Json`?

This is my code:

```
import ast
mystr = b'[{\'1459161763632\': \'this_is_a_test\'}, {\'1459505002853\': "{\'hello\': 12345}"}, {\'1459505708472\': "{\'world\': 98765}"}]'
chunk = str(mystr)
chunk = ast.literal_eval(chunk)
print(chunk)
```

Running from `Python2` I get:

```
[{'1459161763632': 'this_is_a_test'}, {'1459505002853': "{'hello': 12345}"}, {'1459505708472': "{'world': 98765}"}]
```

Running from `Python3` I get:

```
b'[{\'1459161763632\': \'this_is_a_test\'}, {\'1459505002853\': "{\'hello\': 12345}"}, {\'1459505708472\': "{\'world\': 98765}"}]'
```

How can I run from `Python3` and get the same result as `Python2`?

Comment: For Py3: chunk.decode('utf8') or mystr.decode('utf8')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in `mystr` is in `bytes` format, just `decode` it into `ascii` and then evaluate it:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(mystr.decode('ascii'))
[{'1459161763632': 'this_is_a_test'}, {'1459505002853': "{'hello': 12345}"}, {'1459505708472': "{'world': 98765}"}]
```

Or in a more general case, to avoid issues with unicodes characters,

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(mystr.decode('utf-8'))
[{'1459161763632': 'this_is_a_test'}, {'1459505002853': "{'hello': 12345}"}, {'1459505708472': "{'world': 98765}"}]
```

And since, default decoding scheme is `utf-8` which you can see from:

> ```
> >>> help(mystr.decode)
> Help on built-in function decode:
>
> decode(...) method of builtins.bytes instance
>     B.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict') -> str
> ...
> ```

Then, you don't have to specify the encoding scheme:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(mystr.decode())
[{'1459161763632': 'this_is_a_test'}, {'1459505002853': "{'hello': 12345}"}, {'1459505708472': "{'world': 98765}"}]
```

Comment: Good answer, I've added some information about the source of the confusion, namely the 'b' prefix, to an answer below. Feel free to edit that into your own answer if you think it will help other readers.

Comment: @TomRees ... Let's keep it for your answer, you did effort for that, so you must be rewarded... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Iron Fist beat me to the fix. To extend his answer, the 'b' prefix on the string indicates (to python3 but not python2) that the literal should be interpreted as a byte sequence, not a string.

The result is that the .decode method is needed to convert the bytes back into a string. Python2 doesn't make this distinction between the bytes and strings, hence the difference.

See [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) for more information on this.